# 'count' in wp_term_taxonomy without wp_term_relationships

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I lost all my categories and tags in a Wordpress import and I'm trying to get them back. My     'wp_term_relationships' table is empty, which I assume is the problem. I do have a 'wp_term_taxonomy', which includes a "count" column, presumably how many posts are in each category or tag:

http://min.us/mv168n

If the database knows that count, is there any chance it knows which posts are in that count, or is that solely the territory of wp_term_relationships ? Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes all the relations between posts and categories are in   'wp_term_relationships' so unfortunately if you lost that table there is no way to know which post is in which category or taxonomy